# How to specify HTTP timeout for DownloadURL() in Akavache?

Tags: akavache

I am developing an application targetting mobile devices, so I have to consider bad network connectivity. In one use case, I need to reduce the timeout for a request, because if no network is available, that's okay, and I'd fall back to default data *immediately*, *without having the user wait for the HTTP response*.

I found that `HttpMixin.MakeWebRequest()` has a timeout parameter (with default=null) but `DownloadUrl()` never makes use of it, so the forementioned function always waits for up to 15 seconds:

`request.Timeout(timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), 
                                             BlobCache.TaskpoolScheduler).Retry(retries);`

So actually I do not have the option to use a different timeout, or am I missing something?

Thanks for considering a helpful response.

Comment: I saw what you are talking about and am not sure why it is there but, it looks like a timeout related to building the request and not a timeout for the request itself.

Answer (score 2):

So after looking at the signature for `DownloadUrl` in

[HttpMixin.cs](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/blob/develop/src/Akavache/HttpMixin.cs)

I saw what you are talking about and am not sure why it is there but, it looks like the timeout is related to building the request and not a timeout for the request itself.

That being said, in order to set a timeout with a download, you have a couple options that should work.

### Via TPL aka Async Await

`var timeout = 1000;
var task = BlobCache.LocalMachine.DownloadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com").FirstAsync().ToTask();
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
    // task completed within timeout
    //Do Stuff with your byte data here
    //var result = task.Result;
} else { 
    // timeout logic
}`

### Via Rx Observables

`var obs = BlobCache.LocalMachine
                   .DownloadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com")
                   .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                   .Retry(retryCount: 2);
var result = obs.Subscribe((byteData) =>
{
    //Do Stuff with your byte data here
    Debug.WriteLine("Byte Data Length " + byteData.Length);
}, (ex) => { 
    Debug.WriteLine("Handle your exceptions here." + ex.Message);
});`

Comment: The (option) parameter absoluteExpiration to DownloadURL is passed to Insert(), so I assume that's the time to live for the cached content once downloaded. My concern is the parameter timeout in MakeWebRequest which is used as Timeout for the AsyncSubject<WebResponse>. This parameter cannot be changed from outside.
I happened to duplicate that code, lowering the default timeout value, which also is a bad solution.
Either way - there is no way that the timeout parameter gets a non default value, which would be bad design, so propably I'm missing something.